# Replacing a directory with a copy of another directory in Subversion

Tags: svn

Let’s say we have the following two directories in the repository:

```
currentproduction
development
```

And I want to:

1. Rename `currentproduction` to e.g. `archivedproduction`.
2. Copy revision 1234 of `development` as (new) `currentproduction`.

When I do

```
svn ren currentproduction archivedproduction
svn copy -r 1234 development currentproduction
```

Subversion tries to copy `development` *under* (into) `currentproduction` (which is already scheduled for deletion):

```
A    currentproduction\development\file1.txt
A    currentproduction\development\file2.txt
Updated to revision 1234.
svn: Can't add 'currentproduction\development' to a parent directory scheduled for deletion
```

I guess it is because the directory is still there in the working copy until the commit. I *could* do with an intermediate commit:

```
svn ren currentproduction archivedproduction
svn commit
svn copy -r 1234 development currentproduction
```

but that’s not very nice… Isn’t there a way to tell Subversion I want to *replace* the directory with another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying , you could merge `development` to `currentproduction` from the revision you want. That way, you would have only the things that are changed in your commit.

If you created `currentproduction` with a copy of `development`, you would have to [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) the revision that are not present in the `currentproduction` branches.

I advise you to keep a record of every revision you merged to your `currentproduction` branches (unless the server version is > 1.5). You should never merge two revision twice, since it could be seen as a conflict.

```
// Know to which version a branche was created (XX)
svn log --stop-on-copy
svn merge -r XX:1234 development currentproduction
```

I would also suggest you to use this [setup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.using.html) for you repository.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility; however, it adds complexity and possible merge conflicts with no gain for me (in my scenario). And, I do use the setup mentioned, this was a simplified example. ;-) Even though this is not exactly what I needed, I am going to accept the answer as the best I could hope for right now. :-) (I have almost succeeded in doing what I want by hand-editing .svn files, I am going to experiment a bit more in my spare time.)

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would simply rename currentproduction to archivedproduction and just checkout the revision you want to a new directory called currentproduction.

Comment: That’s the same problem: The point is you cannot do that without the intermediate commit. Until the commit, the working copy still contains the `currentproduction` directory and Subversion rejects the checkout with `svn: 'currentproduction' is already a working copy for a different URL`.

Comment: Check it out under another name and rename it when done (rename the directory name using windows not svn)

Comment: What do you mean by “when done”? _When_ would _what_ be done? I would like to do the whole thing in a single commit.

Comment: But you can't delete and use the name of the deleted directory in the same commit! why dont you want to commit between. The commit is the refresh action which updates the svn cache, without it you will have this name conflict. Sorry i missunderstood the queston from the begining.

Comment: “But you can't delete and use the name of the deleted directory in the same commit!” That’s exactly the point of my question, if it is indeed so (and why). ;-) I (as a user) don’t care about a cache or whatever, I have a single replacement operation which I want to do as a single transaction. I can understand SVN has this limitation, but it is definitely a limitation, not a feature.

Comment: Well as fas as i know is SVN more for Programmer than for "normal" user, and programmers have usually lower expectation than users :) (they know how dirty the code behind can be). Joke by side, i find it logically right, think as a windows User, you can copy Directory A into Directory B and you can Rename Directory A to Directory C, but you can not delete/rename subelement and overwrite it using the same name in one step... these are logically two steps so i am afraind we canÄt ignore the SVN Cache issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the `.svn` hidden folder contained in the removed folder, deleted it, then restarted my workspace (I'm using AhnkSVN in M$ VisualStudio), and commited a file in the previously deleted folder without problems.

Anyway, make a backup of the `.svn` folder before deleting it.